# How to copy conditional formatting to another cell so that the custom formula cell variables change based on the location of the cell youre pasting to

Tags: google-sheets

When I copy and paste special > conditional format, it only updates the range, not the formula. Is there a way to paste the custom conditional format to update the variables of the formula as well? For example. If I paste the formula one cell to the right, it would say =G44>=today().

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is already applied as the way you say

i.e. the condition of `G49` in the 2nd screenshot is `=G44=>today()`

Comment: its showing =F44>=today() as the variable for the ranges of F49 and G49. Cell G49 is dependent on the variable F44 not G44 which I need.

Comment: No, it is referring to G44 unless you make it `=$F44>=today()`

Comment: oh I see, it's just not going to show it in the formula bar then?

Comment: Yes, it is 'grouping' and simplifying the things. The same for data validation formula.